# Integrating Resource Compressor like minify-maven-plugin into spring-boot-maven-plugin:run hot reloading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to compress my css and js files into one single fat file for production deployment. solutions like minify-maven-plugin from com.samaxes.maven works fine. I do not want to change my code between production and develoment. Thats the reason why I want to use something like

```
<link href="/css/fat-styles-file.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

during develoment. I like the hot deployment form spring boot:run. If I run my app with spring-boot:run and change some css or js file, after a F5 refresh the results are there. With resource compression its a little bit difficult, because you need to compress before you can use it. Can I configure spring-boot:run in the way itcompresses every time again after refresh ing a website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot can't help you here.

What you're asking for sounds like it would be a capability of the tool that you're using to minify the CSS. Something like Less CSS may be of interest. It can be configured to watch files for changes so that they're automatically compressed when they change. I believe there's also a Maven plugin if you want to also include the compression in your build.